# What in the CSS is causing the images to jump around on hover?

Tags: css

It requires you to sort of move the mouse around the images rather quickly, but you notice that every once in a while, there's a big jump. I can't identify the cause and I was hoping the community might have some insight.

Below is the relevant code and the example can be found on [the website.](http://marlonwayne.com)

```
.square {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    height: 250px;
    display: block;
    background: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 3% auto 10%;
    padding: 0;

    li {

      img {
        width: 100%;
        margin: -40% auto 0;
        transition: .2s;
      }

      img:hover {
        transform: scale(1.2);
      }
    }

    li:nth-child(3n+2) {

    }

    li:nth-child(3n) {

    }
  }
}
```

I suspect the -40% change in the margin for the image is the culprit, but I can't identify why the jumping is so inconsistent.

Comment: img:hover {
        transform: scale(1.2);
      }
This is scaling images to 120% upon hovering

Comment: I don't understand how that's causing it to jump. That's causing it to zoom. And it works properly on most hovers, but every few times you pass over an element, it changes the margin of the element.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem.